# Compiling linux kernel - `make install` asks for LILO. Now what?

Tags: kernel, grub, linux-kernel, make, boot-loader

So I am following this guide to compile my custom kernel - http://library.linode.com/linode-platform/custom-instances/pv-grub-custom-compiled-kernel#sph_compile-and-install-the-kernel

So far so good, but I hit a little road block with `make install`.

```
  AS      arch/x86/boot/header.o
  LD      arch/x86/boot/setup.elf
  OBJCOPY arch/x86/boot/setup.bin
  BUILD   arch/x86/boot/bzImage
Setup is 15328 bytes (padded to 15360 bytes).
System is 5097 kB
CRC c20c9369
Kernel: arch/x86/boot/bzImage is ready  (#2)
[root@li280-195 linux-3.3.3]# make -j3 modules
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CC [M]  drivers/scsi/scsi_wait_scan.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      drivers/scsi/scsi_wait_scan.mod.o
  LD [M]  drivers/scsi/scsi_wait_scan.ko
[root@li280-195 linux-3.3.3]# make
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  CHK     kernel/config_data.h
Kernel: arch/x86/boot/bzImage is ready  (#2)
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
[root@li280-195 linux-3.3.3]# make install
sh /root/build/linux-3.3.3/arch/x86/boot/install.sh 3.3.3 arch/x86/boot/bzImage \
    System.map "/boot"
Cannot find LILO.
```

I understand that `make install` by defaults looks for `LILO` and I know `LILO` is a bootloader. But I don't want to use `LILO` but instead I only care about using `grub`.

What do I do now to have `make install` run correctly?

**UPDATE**

In my `/root/build/linux-3.3.3/arch/x86/install.sh` file, the last 10 lines are:

```
if [ -x /sbin/lilo ]; then
       /sbin/lilo
elif [ -x /etc/lilo/install ]; then
       /etc/lilo/install
else
       sync
       echo "Cannot find LILO."
fi
```

So somehow, I need to edit my `install.sh` to use `grub` instead. Any suggestions?

Comment: What distro are you using?  Many have tools in place to make building and installing customer kernel packages easy.

Comment: distro - arch linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Linode with pv-grub, you can ignore the message about LILO because LILO is not (and cannot be) used on Linode. The kernel image has been copied into `/boot/vmlinuz` at this point.

By default, `make install` updates LILO data if it is installed. It does this as a convenience, because LILO does not know about file systems and has to rely on block numbers to locate the kernel image.

Answer (score 0):

Evidently, your install script has `LILO` as a requirement. Why not simply `make` and then copy the output over to `/boot` and fiddle with `grub` by hand?

Answer (score 0):

The message occurs because you don't have an installkernel script at `/sbin/installkernel`:

```
if [ -x ~/bin/${INSTALLKERNEL} ]; then exec ~/bin/${INSTALLKERNEL} "$@"; fi
if [ -x /sbin/${INSTALLKERNEL} ]; then exec /sbin/${INSTALLKERNEL} "$@"; fi
```

You can write your own script and put it at `/sbin/installkernel`, or use one written by someone else

Comment: What if one has this error in a Red Hat-based distribution (OpenSUSE)?